# Changing graphics when using iPhone Simulator

Tags: graphics, ios-simulator

To increase productivity I'd like our external artists to be able to change graphics in our new iPhone game directly from the iPhone Simulator, so that he can experiment with various graphics without having the source code (for security and practical reasons).

I've already provided him with the simulator, and he got a copy of the game files so it is running on his Mac.

The problem is that all graphical resources is automatically stored into the game application itself, and not as individual files that can be edited.

I'm sure this is better in many ways, but during development it would be handy to incrementally modify the game's graphics, then for the release turn back on packaging.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, you can just right click on the app and open package content. From there all the files can be changed as usual. Guess I just need to know Mac better. :)